# error when using partial render

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

hello I have been trying to use partial render to access the view model of my partial view from the main view

The partial view is a dialog , when I click a button, the dialog is opened and I load it by calling controller here is the code of the controller :

```
public ActionResult ImagesPartial()
{
    ViewBag.Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images_upload"))
                      .Select(fn => "~/images_upload/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
    return PartialView("_ImagesPartial");
}
```

the In my partial view I use this code to show the images and a radio button

```
@foreach(var image in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.Images)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.imageVenteCatalog, image)
    <img src="@Url.Content(image)" alt="Hejsan" width="100" height="100" class='selectable-image'/>
 }
```

finally in my main view I use renderpartial to get which radiobutton has been selected

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_ImagesPartial");}
```

But instead I'm getting an error saying **reference undefined**

any idea of what it could be ?

**EDIT:**

It doesn't matter for viewdata[""] , I have deleted it , the problem is here

**@foreach(var image in (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Images)**

But why would this cause a problem

Comment: where you maintain `ViewData["imageVenteCatalog"]` in your code ?

Comment: i think you need ``Html.RenderAction`` so that action is called and it wil return the ``_ImagesPartial` view`

Answer (score 2):

[`Html.RenderPartial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) does not calls action, it just renders the View, and you want action to be called so that `ViewBag.Images`  is populated, i suspect you want [`Html.RenderAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) instead:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ImagesPartial","ControllerName"); }
```

Comment: This seems legit , I'm having now the value of the radio button and my model is populated with its value , if I want to show the partial view on a dialog , select a radio button , how can I keep my model populated ?

Comment: yeah exactly , and combine the view model of my main view and my popup

Answer (score 0):

For populated with model you have to use as per below :

```
@Html.Partial("_ImagesPartial", Model)
```

In your  view

And Change in your Controller

```
public ActionResult ImagesPartial()
{
    //strore data in your model class data
    return PartialView("_ImagesPartial", pass your model data);
}
```